# Linking to Stack Overflow Meta in chat generates the MSE icon

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, mso-mse-split, onebox

Posting `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/` in chat generates the same icon as posting `http://meta.stackexchange.com/`. Presumably, it should post a nice Meta Stack Overflow icon.

Comment: someone needs to tag this "onebox", but I don't have the reputation to create the tag

Comment: [Done!](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/250040/2)

Comment: @michaelb958 much obliged!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This appears to be the same problem as the one [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250006/2846923). It has been [fixed](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1982479#1982479):

> [We found we had a few settings that were missed during this tricky migration. It should be ok now.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/250023/2846923)